# Automaticalls wrap Wordpress image into [caption] shortcode

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

I'm just developing my own wordpress theme. 
However, a editor just complaint that the image caption he has entered won't be displayed on the website. After a little research I found out that Wordpress does not automatically add the caption of an uploaded image when you insert the image into a post.

> Example: I click on "add media" in my post and upload the image
>   peter.jpg. After that I enter "My caption" in the captions field and
>   click on the insert button. Now the picture appears in my WYSIWIG
>   editor from wordpress but the caption is missing. When I now edit the
>   image I see that the caption field remaind empty. If I enter a caption
>   now it wraps the whole image into a [caption] shortcode and everything
>   is fine.

Well this funny behaviour is normal in Worpress (as far as I found on some articles by google). The caption entered for any image will not automatically appear if you insert the image to the editor field of a post.

So I do not understand why this makes sense but my editors complain "No sir, I do not like typing the caption twice …" so I tried to automatically take over the caption on insert by

```
    add_filter('image_send_to_editor', 'automatically_wrap_my_post_images', 11, 8);
function automatically_wrap_my_post_images($html, $id, $caption, $title, $align, $url, $size, $alt){
   return '[caption id="attachment_'.$id.'" align="align'.$align.'" width="620"]'.$html.$caption.'[/caption]';
}//wrap_my_div
```

and wrap the whole image in a [caption] shortcode.

But nothing worked well, the shortcode than was removed after I clicked on save once and only the Text remained.

So is there any easy way to automatically wrap any post image in the editor width the regular [caption] shortcode and the original images caption. So that you have no need to type the caption a second time after inserting the image into the post editor?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry this is not directly answering your question about the captions (there should be a plugin for this but if not your code looks like it should work).
This "funny behaviour" is not normal of WordPress and only happens because of

a) php memory issues (lack of sufficient ram, csf firewall killing processes that take too long/use too much ram)
b) mysql not performing properly due to hard disk filling up and/or not having the mysql databases reside in its own partition for optimal performance
c) the server tmpdisk is full because session caches were not cleared due to sloppy code of plugins or theme or simply because it's ridiculously small like 500MB or something.

WordPress runs beautifully if the server it sits on doesn't have any of these issues.